# how to make addition of the value of checkbox with the vale of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

here i want to add the value of multiple checkbox with `textbox(id=TextBox1)` and display it in `textbox(id=TextBox2)` without using any button.
example: if i m selecting `checkbox1` and `checkbox3` so the total would be 30 and it will be added with `textbox1`(which is autopopulated user cannot edit it) and afterthat it should be displayed in `textbox2` without using any button

```
     <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" value="5"/>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" value="15"/>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" value="25"/>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" value="35"/>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

Comment: And what have you tried? ;)

Comment: Only javascript or u are loading jquery as well?

Comment: i have tried using javascript but it gives me only the total of checkbox

Comment: yaa also jquery

Comment: then why you are tagged to c#?

Comment: Do you want to display the total of values of checkboxes in both textboxes?

Comment: no we have to just add the total of checkbox with textbox1 and the final total will be display in textbox2

Comment: @Bunny - Please see my answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use C#, you need to postback changes and refresh the content of `TextBox2`:

## ASP.NET/C# (server-side)

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" value="5" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" value="15" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" value="25" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" value="35" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    int sum = Convert.ToInt32( this.TextBox1.Text );
    if ( this.CheckBox1.Checked ) sum += Convert.ToInt32( this.CheckBox1.Attributes["value"] );
    if ( this.CheckBox2.Checked ) sum += Convert.ToInt32( this.CheckBox2.Attributes["value"] );
    if ( this.CheckBox3.Checked ) sum += Convert.ToInt32( this.CheckBox3.Attributes["value"] );
    if ( this.CheckBox4.Checked ) sum += Convert.ToInt32( this.CheckBox4.Attributes["value"] );
    this.TextBox2.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

But I would prefer jQuery for this task:

*Edit: since you were asking **that kindly** for some jQuery code, here it is:*

## jQuery (client-side)

**Remark**: The attribute "value" will not be written to the `input`s in the html output. You could use `data-value` instead, then the input will be embedded inside a `span` with the specified `data-value` attribute.

```
<script>
    function clientclick() {
        var tb = $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>");
        var sum = parseInt(tb.val());
        var cb = $("#<%=CheckBox1.ClientID %>");
        if (cb.is(":checked")) sum += parseInt(cb.parent("*[data-value]").data("value"));
        cb = $("#<%=CheckBox2.ClientID %>");
        if (cb.is(":checked")) sum += parseInt(cb.parent("*[data-value]").data("value"));
        cb = $("#<%=CheckBox3.ClientID %>");
        if (cb.is(":checked")) sum += parseInt(cb.parent("*[data-value]").data("value"));
        cb = $("#<%=CheckBox4.ClientID %>");
        if (cb.is(":checked")) sum += parseInt(cb.parent("*[data-value]").data("value"));
        $("#<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>").val(sum);
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" data-value="5" onclick="clientclick()"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" data-value="15" onclick="clientclick()"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" data-value="25" onclick="clientclick()"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" data-value="35" onclick="clientclick()"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

This is quick'n'dirty but I keep it up to you to combine this approach with the other answers using `$.each`

Comment: then give the jquery solution it would be very helpfull to us.

Comment: I added a small example with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

This answer is js with html. I hope it will work for your asp as well

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var sum;
 $("input:checkbox[name=vehicle]").change(function(){
  sum=0;
   $("input:checkbox[name=vehicle]:checked").each(function(){
   sum=sum+parseInt($(this).val())
});
var txtValue=parseInt($('#txt1').val());
$('#txt2').val(txtValue+sum)
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="5">5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="15">15<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="25">25<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="35">35<br>

<input type='text' id='txt1' value='0' />
<input type='text'  id='txt2' />
```

Comment: we need this answer in aspx control

Comment: we need this in aspx controls

Comment: @Bunny You will get that. use the id of the text box to get the value. If you are  note getting, inspect the textbox using developer option of browser to get the id of text box. May be some contentplaceholderid added while converting asp control to html control